# Can disabling autowiring and using annotation instead for services in Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, autowired

In the DI there is Autowiring, annotation definition and PHP definition.

In Symfony 3.3 the autowiring is enabled by default. So if I disable the autowiring, can I use the annotation to define a service?

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @Inject({"my.specific.service"})
     */
    public function __construct(Bar $param1)
    {
    }
}
```

> Update : Use JMSDiExtraBundle

```
namespace MediaBundle\Net;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;

/**
 * @Service("some.service.id", public=false, environments = {"prod", "test", "dev"})
 */
class Foo
{
    private $em;
    private $session;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *     "em" = @Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager"),
     *     "session" = @Inject("session")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct($em, $session)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $session;
    }
}
```

Calling the service in the controller:

```
namespace MediaBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/media")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $someService = $this->get('some.service.id');

        return $this->render('MediaBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Result : `You have requested a non-existent service "some.service.id".`

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  I don't use the JMSDi bundle myself but I imagine it would work just fine.

Comment: I installed JMSDibundle.but when I call the service it can't be found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your service injected somewhere? If not, it will be dropped from the container due to `public=false`, see http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-improved-private-services

Comment: Yes , change the public=true will fix the problem. So Finally it is possible to use annotation to define a service in symfony 3 by using JMSDibundle.

Comment: So now the question becomes: why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I consider that the annotation definition is more maintainable than the YAML/XML definition. The name of service is defined in the some file, so I can get the name of the service from the class instead searchinghim  from the yml or xml file.

Comment: It was a bit rhetorical since I know some people really like annotations and other don't.  In the example in your question if I am looking at your controller action then I doubt I would have any idea where some.service.id was defined though I assume you would use a doc type hint at least.  But here is the kicker, with autowire, indexAction(Foo $someService) would do the trick.  No need for a special some.service.id and no need to use the service locater pattern.  No need for annotation and no need (in most cases) for a services.yaml entry.  Just something to think about.